# Multithreading and gdb

Tags: multithreading

Can someone please tell me interview type questions related to multithreading and GDB.

I already know Deadlock, race condition, synchronization and basics of threads.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Some sample questions:

1. How do you list out all the threads?
2. How do you set breakpoints in individual threads?
3. How do you see stacktrace of a particular thread?
4. Your program is in a deadlock; How do you find the root cause using gdb?

There is no end to questions. I would suggest that the best way to learn is to get knees deep in the dirt and play for yourself:

- Make a sample multi-threaded program, debug it and try to find all possible info about all the threads.
- Put some deadlock situation, and then debug it.